# Maintain DropdownList Selected value in mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have a DropDown and on selcted indexchanged it forcefully postback and Binds a table,but after postback it didn't maintain the state.

my view is

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.fkSubMenuID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.list,"Select" 

,new { id = "ddlSubMenu",onchange="SelectedIndexChanged()" })
```

and my controller is

```
public ActionResult ChildMenuOfSubMenu()

    {
        if (Session["DDlId"] == null || Convert.ToInt32(Session["DDlId"]) == 0)
        {
            UlrikenEntities dc = new UlrikenEntities();
            var query = (from m in dc.ulriken_tblChildMenu
                         join sb in dc.ulriken_tblSubMenu on m.fkSubMenuID equals sb.pkSubMenuID
                         where m.Status == true && sb.fkMainMenuID == 1
                         select m).ToList();
            Ulriken.Models.ChildMenu ObjHomeEvents = new Models.ChildMenu();
            ObjHomeEvents.FormDetails = query;
            FillDeptName();
            Session["DDlId"] = null;
            return View(ObjHomeEvents);
        }
        else
        {
            Int64 id = Convert.ToInt64(Session["DDlId"]);
            UlrikenEntities dc = new UlrikenEntities();
            var query = (from m in dc.ulriken_tblChildMenu
                         join sb in dc.ulriken_tblSubMenu on m.fkSubMenuID equals sb.pkSubMenuID
                         where m.Status == true && m.fkSubMenuID == id && sb.fkMainMenuID==1
                         select m).ToList();
            Ulriken.Models.ChildMenu ObjHomeEvents = new Models.ChildMenu();
            ObjHomeEvents.FormDetails = query;
            FillDeptName();
            //string ddlValue= ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("ddlSubMenu");

            Session["DDlId"] = null;
            return View(ObjHomeEvents);
        }


        //return View();
    }
```

and my javascript function is :

```
   function SelectedIndexChanged() {        

        document.demoForm.submit();

  }
```

Somebody guide me where am i doing wrong

Comment: Show us the code of SelectedIndexChanged() .

Comment: function SelectedIndexChanged() {       
        document.demoForm.submit();        

    }

Comment: e.g if i select 3rd value of dropdownlist after postback it goes to the first one.

Comment: @user3848417 You can `Ajax Form` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller action has no parameters... You need at least one parameter in the controller action to retrieve the value selected by the user.

```
public ActionResult ChildMenuOfSubMenu(int fkSubMenuID) 
{
    // ....
}
```

Probably will be better to have a method to show the view when the request is an HTTP GET and another one to handle the form submit (HTTP POST):

```
public ActionResult ChildMenuOfSubMenu() 
{
    // This method gets called in a HTTP GET
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChildMenuOfSubMenu(int fkSubMenuID) 
{
    // This one gets called when user performs the submit to the form
}
```